# Can I test events in protractorjs/cucumberjs

Tags: angular, protractor, webdriver, cucumberjs

cucumberjs not java

I have an angular component that uses a directive to change focus when x characters are entered into the input.  I would like to verify in my cucumber tests.

1) does webElement.sendKeys trigger key events?  I have tried sendKeys(1,9,9,9) but don'tknow if the events are being triggered

2) how can I listen for DOM events like paste, copy, keyup, etc... in a cucumber test?

I can't find any complete examples for cucumberjs and not sure the java examples really translate.

Comment: In my current project that I work on, we use WebDriverIO (https://webdriver.io/). I am not exactly sure with your syntax but yes, I think `webElement.sendKeys` will send keys to the input box. So try `webElement.sendKeys('hello');`. Your test can be, set focus on the first input, send the keys, expect this input not to have focus, expect the next input to have focus. I use WebDriverIO with Cucumber/Gherkin on top of it so for me WebDriverIO's API is simpler but I am sure it can be done with what you have as well.

Comment: I know sendkeys will update input box.  The question is about what if any events get triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, None of the End to End test automation tools like Protractor, WebdriverIO, NightwatchJS and CypressIO support this natively. Unit testing tools might have a solution for this and I found below info on Googling. Hope it is of some help to you.

[How can I unit test an event listener on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069515/how-can-i-unit-test-an-event-listener-on-an-input-field)

Comment: Thanks for that.   With the recent(?) focus on reactive programming, we need a tool to test event reactions lol

Comment: Yeah. Maybe the tools should support this kind of thing natively.